# ilike syntax in sqlalchemy python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-like

I am new to sqlalchemy and was working on a project.

I am stuck in querying using `ilike`'s syntax:

```
query = query.filter(or_(*[Package.name==pkg for pkg in packages]))
```

I want pkg to be case-insestive, how should I use `ilike` for that?

I tried this:

```
query = query.filter(or_(*[Package.name.ilike(pkg) for pkg in package]))
```

but didnt work.

What else should I do?

or there is something better than `ilike`?

thanks!

Comment: Will `pkg` match directly? If not, you might want wildcards. `ilike("%"+pkg+"%")`

Comment: yeah, pkg will match directly...like if i am searching for pkg like "wxgtk3", it should produces result but if i am using these codes : query = query.filter(or_(*[Package.name==pkg for pkg in packages])) .It produces no results (i.e it seaches for only case sensetive pkg)

Comment: Have you considered `func.lower(Package.name) == pkg.lower()`, if `packages` is an iterable of strings. (Replace `func.lower` with what ever your DB's function for lower casing a string is) You could even do `filter(func.lower(Package.name).in_([pkg.lower() for pkg in packages]))` instead of the `or_` unpacking.